# setState returns null , unable to set state for svg

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, state

Im using d3 to select a svg component to render. I wish to store this svg within my state , however im always getting back the result of null when i use the setState method:

```
this.setState(
    {
     svg : d3.select("svg") ,
     svgGroup: d3.select("svg").append("g")
    },
    console.log(this.state.svg),
    this.graph = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({}).setDefaultEdgeLabel(function() {
      return {};
    }) 
    );
```

in my console:

```
null
```

Is there a way for me to store this svg in my state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to wrap second argument into a callback function :

```js
this.setState(
  {
    svg: d3.select('svg'),
    svgGroup: d3.select('svg').append('g'),
  },
  () => {
    console.log(this.state.svg),
    this.graph = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({}).setDefaultEdgeLabel(() => ({}));
  }
);
```

If it does not solve the problem, it means `d3.select('svg')` returns null.

Also, I'm not familiar with d3 but I'm not sure you should use state to store what you call a `svg component`. If you need to access a component's API, [ref](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) might be what you're looking for.